# AngularJS $interval function continues after route change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a function inside a controller which is based on setInterval. I noticed that after first calling it, it worked fine but continued even after the route changed. Afterwards i tried using the native $interval service which would automatically track changes in scope. The problem however remains. So now i have two questions. The first one is what can i do so that i use a repeated function inside a specific controller that stops when the user leaves that route? Also why does the scope function continue since i've changed scopes?

UPDATE - Code is like this

```
$scope.refreshScore() {
        ....
      }
$scope.refreshMe = function(){
  $interval($scope.refreshScore, 10000);
}
```

Comment: I used this solution and it work good: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24324902/1393774

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Maybe try canceling it on the destroy event of the scope.

```
$scope.refreshScore() {
   ....
}
var intervalPromise;
$scope.refreshMe = function(){
    intervalPromise = $interval($scope.refreshScore, 10000);
}
$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
    if(intervalPromise)
        $interval.cancel(promiseFromInterval);   
});
```

`$interval` may not be the best solution for this, especially if it is some async operation. If you absolutely have to have some timed operation that you want to occur preciously every x ms I would use something like this:

```
var refreshingPromise; 
var isRefreshing = false;
$scope.startRefreshing = function(){
   if(isRefreshing) return;
   isRefreshing = true;
   (function refreshEvery(){
         //Do refresh
         //If async in then in callback do...
         refreshingPromise = $timeout(refreshEvery,10000)
    }());
}
```

Then do the same thing as above

If you're having trouble canceling the refresh you might try subscribing to some sort of route change event. And doing it there.

Comment: I updated with the code. Could you explain a little further what to change? Also why does the function keeps getting called since i am using the Angular wrapper of setInterval?

Comment: It is only a wrapper it does not change what setInterval does, Can I ask what you are trying to refresh? Perhaps using `$interval` is not the best solution

Comment: I need to refresh a stream of events received from the server by polling every 10secs to check if new events occured. This works perfectly in the route it was supposed but continues after route change. I tried using $scope.on($destroy,...) but it doesn't work for me... Maybe i'm doing something wrong... I get that $interval is just a wrapper but isn't it supposed to attach a $watch and stop on route changes?

Comment: Can't seem to make it work... Maybe it's simple and i can't see it. Anyway, thanks for the help... I'll give it a few more tries.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
    $scope.refreshScore = function() {
       // your logic here
    }
    var promise = $interval($scope.refreshScore, 10000);
    $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
        if(promise)
            $interval.cancel(promise);   
    });
```

It will destroy the interval when you change the route.

Comment: (I don't think you need to check `promise`) but this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Startec In this particular example you are correct that checking the promise is not necessary. But, in practice, this promise could have been cancelled at some other point in the application. So really it is a good idea to ensure the promise exists before attempting to cancel it.

Answer (score 2):

For one simple solution, you can just use `$location.$$path` before you fire the event associated with the interval.

If the path does not correlate with the ui, don't fire it and cancel it.