# $interval function continues when I change routes

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a problem regarding an `$interval` function continues when I change routes.

This is the code:

```
  x = 2;

 var multiply = function () {
     x = x * 2;
     if (x == 134217728) {
         $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
         $scope.stop = 0;
     }
 }


 $scope.Result = function () {
     $scope.stop = $interval(multiply, 1000);
 }

 $scope.Result();
```

When `x<134217728`,  I change the route to move to another page. The problem is that `$interval` doesn't stop after the route changes. I store the promise in the variable `stop` in the `$scope` model. I think `$scope` doesn't destroy after routes change and that is why `$interval` continues.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use `$interval.cancel($scope.stop);` when `$locationChangeSuccess` is invoked in your controller/service.

E.G.

```
controller('MyController', function($rootScope, $interval) {
  $scope.stop = $interval(yourOperation, 1000);

  var dereg = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $interval.cancel($scope.stop);
    dereg();
  });

  function yourOperation() {}
};
```

Comment: There is also the more generically useful $destroy event: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/16/angularjs-listening-for-destroy.aspx

Comment: yes that works too :), but it doesn't work if the $interval is not inside a controller(a scope to destroy).

Comment: e.g. a route without a controller but contains a resolve which has an interval :), although such an example might be rare.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are injecting $interval in other controller too, you can either set the $interval
in other controller or you can cancel the $interval with $locationChangesuccess as mentioned by @ryeballar.